# Records that was modified less than 5 and record that was modified more than 5 days ( and percentage )

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns `Service_date` and `Modify_date`
within the same table i want to know the number of records that passed 5 days till *modify* and the one that didn't pass and also the percentage of records that didn't pass

***Wanted Output:***

> *(Count of records that passed 5 days) | (Count of records that didn't pass 5 days) | ( %percentage% of Records that didn't pass 5 days)*

Comment: fixed title i meant modified*

Answer (score 1):

If we consider `Service_date` only,

```
select count(case when Service_date >  trunc(sysdate) - 5 then 1 end ) as new_records,
       count(case when Service_date <= trunc(sysdate) - 5 then 1 end ) as old_records,
       100*(count(case when Service_date >  trunc(sysdate) - 5 then 1 end ) / count(*))
       as percentage_for_new
  from maintenance;
```

would give what you want, but I think you need a starting date for old records. `Modify_date` might be considered in the same manner.

Comment: extra info: Days from Service_date to Modify_date ( did it passed 5 days till it got modified?)   and within specific time like q1 or 2018